# How to keep different SVN working copies of the same branch in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, svn

I frequently have multiple SVN working copies checked out. For example, I may have trunk-merge for merging branches into trunk, trunk-review to review other people's changes, and trunk-feature1 to trunk-featureN for work started. These all have the same repository URL.

If I import one of these projects into Eclipse (Kepler, Build id: 20130614-0229, Mac OS), that works fine. But I cannot import another one because these would have the same project name and Eclipse cannot handle that. To switch between my working copies, I now have to close the project, delete it from Eclipse, and import another one. Then Eclipse takes its 5 minutes to scan, index, and compile everything. In some older Eclipse versions I could use a symlink as described in 
[Eclipse Workspace/Project Setup Using Symlinks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011667/eclipse-workspace-project-setup-using-symlinks) but that does not seem to work anymore on Eclipse Kepler (it resolves the symlink when importing the project).

I know that I could use feature branches on the trunk-featureN working copies, but often the features are not big enough for a branch, and eventually merging becomes a nightmare.

I do not want to use SVN switch on the workspace because in many cases the working copies will be modified.

How can I easily switch between (modified) working copies of the same project in Eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't or don't want to change the project name based on the working copy (admittedly, that's a bit of a pain), then the best option is to use separate Workspaces. If you're not familiar with Eclipse's concept of workspaces, the gist is that a Workspace is a logical container of projects and metadata (eg, stuff you configure in the Preferences dialog). Projects that are logically part of a workspace do not have to be physically located in the workspace folder, although that's the default location when creating a new project unless you tell it otherwise. You can even import the same project into different workspaces, if you want.

In you case, I recommend using *File* > *Switch Workspace...* > *Other...* to create a new workspace in which to import a different working copy of your project. You can even export/import Preferences from one workspace to another.